# How to backtrack when crawling with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to write a general crawler that will crawl one site at a time. However, I would like it to backtrack when it has seen a page that I deem relevant.
For example, I want to extract job ads from a company website and I have an **ML** model that can classify a job ad page. When the crawler hits a job ad and the model is predicting that that is a job ad I would like it to go a step back (hopefully to the career page) and navigate from there to the other job ad pages. Is this possible to do with the help of **Scrapy**?

Comment: you can't move back,you have to get all ads and send as list to `career page` and if it will not match then get first from list and rest send to `career page` (with different URL). etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since Scrapy is using callback driven asynchronous engine you can't really backtrack implicitly. You need to take advantage of `meta` keyword:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    yield Request(url, meta={'product_id': 123}, callback=self.parse_product)

def parse_product(self, response):
    product_id = response.meta['product_id']
```

You can also access request response was made with `response.request` however using meta is generally a more robust solution.

Comment: I add that `Scrapy 2.x` can use [Request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) with `cb_kwargs={'product_id': 123}` and get it as `def parse_product(self, response, product_id):`